# How can I detect uiview is an activated viewport

Tags: revit-api

I need to detect whether a Uiview is a standard opened view or if it is an activated viewport on a sheet. Querying the uiview’s view Id returns the Id of the activated viewport's view. I have found no direct way to detect that a uiview is actually a sheet with an activated viewport.

I am already tracking opened views in the view activated event for another purpose. So I considered storing the view Id with the uiview hashcode for later checking that it was indeed a sheetview prior to becoming an activated view. Unfortunately, and I think in opposition to standard use, the uiview hashcode is not stable. Multiple hashcode requests from the uiview object return different values.

Does anyone have a way to detect this condition? I need to be able to use the the methods on the uiview still. So any help to find the actual child windows I would like to relate to the uiview object. The view still says "Sheet: ..." in the title when a view is activated.

Comment: Hashcode is not stable because when you get an UIView, it's a managed wrapper that is encapsulating a native object. Each time you request for it, a new wrapper is created. And even if it was stable, hashes are not guaranteed to be unique (it's just used to put objects into compartments).

Comment: Seems impossible to use an unstable hashcode for storage, comparison, etc. But I understand that the object I am receiving is not the same wrapping object each time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            TaskDialog mainDialog = new TaskDialog("Hello, viewport check!");
            mainDialog.MainInstruction = "Hello, viewport check!";
            mainDialog.MainContent = 
                    "Sadly Revit API doesn't automatically know if the user is in an active viewport. " 
                    + "Please click 'Yes' if your are, or 'No' if your not.";

            mainDialog.AddCommandLink(TaskDialogCommandLinkId.CommandLink1,
                     "Yes, I am in an active viewport on a sheet.");
            mainDialog.AddCommandLink(TaskDialogCommandLinkId.CommandLink2, 
                            "No, I am just in an ordinary view.");

            mainDialog.CommonButtons = TaskDialogCommonButtons.Close;
            mainDialog.DefaultButton = TaskDialogResult.Close;


            TaskDialogResult tResult = mainDialog.Show();

            bool YesOrNo = true;

            if (TaskDialogResult.CommandLink1 == tResult)
            {
                    YesOrNo = true;

            }

            else if (TaskDialogResult.CommandLink2 == tResult)
            {
                    YesOrNo = false;
            }
                           else{
            return;
               }
```

Comment: Hilarious. And best solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewSheet GetAllViewports method to determine all the viewports on a given sheet. Using that, you could put together a bi-directional dictionary lookup system map any sheet to all the viewports it hosts and vice versa. That should help solve your task. Here is some example usage:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/04/determining-the-size-and-location-of-viewports-on-a-sheet.html

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't quite understand how that helps me find out that a uiview is currently showing an activated viewport. Can you explain further?

Comment: you said that you have access to the id of the activated viewport's view. i thought it would be useful to stuff that into such a lookup system. i guess i do not quite understand your problem.

Comment: Let's say i have a floor plan view open and then i also have a sheet open with that same floor plan on it. Then I activate the floor plan viewport on the open sheet view. I now have two UIViews that report that they are the same floor plan. I have no way to tell which is the floor plan view and which is the activated viewport of the same floor plan.  What i need to know is whether a UIVIew is currently in the state of showing an active viewport. Which one is the activated viewport and which one is the standard opened view?

Comment: sorry, i still do not understand. you can identify which view is active, can't you? and you have its element id. and you can therefore open it and ask it for its type. i believe i will probably never understand this problem without looking at a reproducible case: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b. maybe it would help if you explain what the ultimate goal and use case for all of this is.

Comment: i asked the development team, and they have no suggestion, i'm afraid. looks like a hack is required, if there is a solution at all. you can raise a wish for this in the Revit Idea Station and ensure that it gets lots of votes: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-ideas/idb-p/302

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I have a solution in place that has been working well since i posted the question. I am only using the standard API and APIUI since I don't want to do anything hack-ish. I am also able to detect closing of a view which is another thing missing in the API. I would appreciate having this ability out of the box though alleviating my code of the burden. Additionally, after knowing that I am operating in an activated viewport, an adjustment transform must be used so that my commands operate properly in any spatial orientation. This has all added unnecessary difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Im late to the party - but another way to sense if the user is in a viewport is to investigate the `Process.MainWindow` title. Something like this (in RevitPythonShell):

```
import threading, clr
from System.Diagnostics import Process

# need winform libraries for feedback form only
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import Form, Label

app = __revit__.Application
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
ui = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument

def lookAtWindow(activeView):

    # Looking for one of three conditions:
    # 1. User is on a sheet (ActiveView will be DrawingSheet)
    # 2. User is in an active ViewPort on a sheet (ActiveView will NOT be be DrawingSheet, but MainWindowTitle will contain " - [Sheet: " string)
    # 3. User is on a View (neither of the previous two conditions)

    result = False 

    if str(activeView.ViewType) == 'DrawingSheet':            
        result = 'Youre on a sheet'
    else:
        processes = list(Process.GetProcesses())
        for process in processes:
            window = process.MainWindowTitle
            if window and 'Autodesk Revit '+app.VersionName[-4:] in window and ' - [Sheet: ' in window and ' - '+doc.Title+']' in window:
                result = 'I reckon youre in a Viewport'
    if not result:
        result = 'so you must be in a '+str(activeView.ViewType) 

    form = Form()
    form.Width = 300
    form.Height = 100
    label = Label()
    label.Width = 280
    label.Height = 70
    label.Text = result
    label.Parent = form 
    form.ShowDialog()

# need to close RevitPythonShell console before checking MainWindowTitle, so run on timer
threading.Timer(1, lookAtWindow, [ui.ActiveView]).start()

__window__.Close()
```